# Getting error when I moved codebase from one host to another

Tags: c#, .net, windows, hosting

"I hosted my website in .net in one of the host, now i changed my host to the new one.

But When I Run the site I am getting below error."

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page
>
> is invalid.
>
> Detailed Error Information
>
> Module IIS Web Core
>
> Notification Unknown
>
> Handler Not yet determined
>
> Error Code 0x8007000d
>
> Config Error Configuration file is not well-formed XML
>
> Config File \?\D:\InetPub\vhosts******.com\httpdocs\web.config
>
> Requested URL http://******:80/
>
> Physical Path
>
> Logon Method Not yet determined
>
> Logon User Not yet determined Config Source 168: 169:

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is usually because a IIS or other Windows feature that was installed on the previous OS is not installed on the new one.  Check your "feature tree" and compare what is enabled where it is working vs. where it is not.

Comment: i have only the published code from old server how to check the features...Please coorect me if i am wrong